# Warping Components

Tags: android, components

Is it possible to 'warp' or 'bend' components (For example, a `SeekBar` that is shaped like this:`)` with the button moving across the arc)? Or is this only achievable through a custom component?

Comment: Possibly duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496459/is-it-possible-to-change-the-shape-of-android-seek-bar or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163215/android-styling-seek-bar